# populate tableView with plist

Tags: iphone, xcode4.3

It is 10 days that i am fighting to populate a tableView with a plist.
Here my the plist.
    item 0
    
        description
        descr1 
        image
        image1.jpg
        name
        mom
    
    item 1
    
        description
        descr2
        image
        image2.png
        name
        dad

I need to populate with the string "name".
I tried to post my code but the form it is always saying my code is not formatted properly so i cannot post it.
thanks for any help.

Comment: add four space before in your code line or lines.. and then try to post. may be it's post your code here :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look to Apple tutorial here http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/CreateConfigureTableView/CreateConfigureTableView.html

Simple if you follow this guide.

Comment: Thanks. I will read for sure. i Have already populate my tableView view with plist but just in the case i am using am array and string. when I am trying to do it with a dictionary and string is not working..

Comment: Thanks Divol... with the tutorial you gave to me I sort out my problem.

Comment: Hi Divol.. I want to set as background an image. Have you got a tutorial for that.  Thanks in advance..

Comment: You could have a look to these messages (sorry for the formating) -(void) addBackView{
 
  UIImageView * aview =  [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:someimage];
  

  aview.tag=2012;
   [self addSubview:aview];
  [self  sendSubviewToBack:aview];
  [aview release];
     
}

-(void)removeBackView{
 UIImageView * aview = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:2012];
 if (aview){
  [aview removeFromSuperview];
 }
 
}

Comment: if you want to center your back view -(void) centeredBackView{
 
 UIImageView * aview = (UIImageView *)[self viewWithTag:2012];
 if (aview){
  aview.frame= CGRectMake(0,0,1024,1024); // if the background image is 1024*1024
  aview.center = CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2,((self.bounds.size.height)/2));
  
 }
 
}

Comment: Thank you.. As i guess you understood I am newbie on this.. I tried I've got 3 errors. the first : [self addSubview:aview]; in this point " No visible interface for viewController declares the selector 'addSubView'. second : [self sendSubviewToBack:aview]" No visible interface for viewController declares the selector 'sendViewToBack'. The last is in the second part: [self viewWithTag:2012] " No visible interface for viewController declares the selector 'viewWithTag' All the errors are on the self. I guess i miss something before.  Thank you very much for your great help.

Comment: these messages was exctacted from an imageview subclass, here the interface:(i prefixed the @ with a \ ) \@interface BackgroundView : UIImageView
{


  

}

-(void) addBackView;
-(void) centeredBackView;
-(void)removeBackView;
\@end

Comment: Hi Divol, Sorry to bother you.I need your help if it is not a problem.(sorry this formatting).I did this code:view.imageMappeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[self.news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"image"]];
view.labelMappeString = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[self.news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"note"]]; I've populated a  TableView with plist,When I select the row I'm pushing a new View with an image and text,this image and text are inside the plist,I want show in my view an image from a website.Do you think it is possible ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, you can init an image with an url : NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:yoururl]; and UIImage * image = [UIImage imageWithData:data]; you can add this image into your UIImageView or any view you like. one thing : dataWithContentsOfURL is synchronous.